# Getting all the data from json?

Tags: jquery

How do I get all the data from Json Output?

```
$.getJSON("Test.php", { Id:Id}, function(json) {
        alert(json);
});
```

I am aware of: `alert(json.name)`

Comment: json has all the data, please tell what output u want and what is coming right now

Comment: I get [object Object] when doing alert(json);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could serialize the object again:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(json));
```

Does not make much sense to me though. If it is only for debugging, get Firebug (you can create a new profile that you will only use for developing or use Google Chrome).

If you actually want to do something with the response, then you have to access the values of the object, like

```
json.bar
// or
json[1].bar
```

But you have to know the structure of the object obviously.

You can also always loop over the properties of an object with `for...in` or over an array with a `for` loop.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that you dont know what values does the json object has.
try this:

```
jQuery.each(json, function(key, value) {
   //send each key with his value to the console
   console.log("key", key, "value", value);
   //or maybe to the documento
   document.write("key: " + key + " value: " + value);
});
```

Also read this [tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Types) I understand a lot of jquery and javascript after I read it